# SQL Server 2005 Query - Count of a Sum

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to do a sum of a count. I'm running the below query. I want a sum of BrowserCount however I want to return the datatable which is returned by this query. Is that possible should I be using a return value? Or is there another way? I realize there's been a decent amount of posts on this but I couldn't get this to run using them.

```
SELECT  UA.Browser_ID
      , B.Browser_Name_NM
      , COUNT(B.Browser_Name_NM) AS BrowserCount
FROM    llc.User_Agent_TB AS UA
        LEFT JOIN llc.Browser_TB AS B ON UA.Browser_ID = B.Browser_ID
GROUP BY B.Browser_Name_NM
      , UA.Browser_ID
ORDER BY BrowserCount DESC
```

This is sql server 2005 so I can't do a group of a set.  I also have tried to get a union of two queries to work and it keeps giving me a syntax error.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; do you want an additional row showing the grand total?  Can you give an example?

Comment: I have a count of COUNT(B.Browser_Name_NM) AS BrowserCount which returns the amount of times a browser showed up.  I want a sum of the row.

Comment: Example:
Firefox        5
IE             3

I want to return 8.

Comment: Do you need the names too or is it enough to have to total number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be what you're after:

```
SELECT  UA.Browser_ID
  , B.Browser_Name_NM
  , COUNT(B.Browser_Name_NM) AS BrowserCount
FROM    llc.User_Agent_TB AS UA
    LEFT JOIN llc.Browser_TB AS B ON UA.Browser_ID = B.Browser_ID
GROUP BY B.Browser_Name_NM
  , UA.Browser_ID
WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY BrowserCount DESC
```

See here for some more detailed examples, including how to show a more meaningful summary line

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020145951/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/073003-1.aspx

Comment: Also good to be used together with the `GROUPING` function, to know which row is what: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178544.aspx